# Wrong ouput in dataframe: Copying a calculation for every row separately

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, math, correlation

I'm looking for a modification of below function so that the calculation of the autocorrelation is done for every row, and not only for the first row.

Below function is the one I use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel("directory\\file.xlsx")

def autocorr(x, t):
     y = np.corrcoef(np.array([x[0:len(x)-t], x[t:len(x)]]))
     return y

df1 = df.copy(deep=True) 

for index,row in df1.iterrows():
     df1["output1"] = autocorr(df.T[0], 1)[0, 1]
     df1["output2"]= autocorr(df.T[0], 2)[0, 1]
     df1["output3"]= autocorr(df.T[0], 3)[0, 1]
     df1["output4"]= autocorr(df.T[0], 4)[0, 1]
     df1["output5"]= autocorr(df.T[0], 5)[0, 1]
     df1["output6"]= autocorr(df.T[0], 6)[0, 1]
     df1["output7"]= autocorr(df.T[0], 7)[0, 1]
     df1["output8"]= autocorr(df.T[0], 8)[0, 1]
     df1["output9"]= autocorr(df.T[0], 9)[0, 1]
     df1["output10"]= autocorr(df.T[0], 10)[0, 1]
     df1["output11"]= autocorr(df.T[0], 11)[0, 1]
     df1["output12"]= autocorr(df.T[0], 12)[0, 1]



df1
```

But it keeps giving the following result (so the result for the first row, copied over the second, third,..row):

[image: result]

I've tried everything but I can't do it for every row separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the builtin autocorr function from Pandas?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.autocorr.html

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.arange(1,10), np.arange(10, 1, -1)]), index=['a', 'b'])
     df
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
a   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
b  10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2
df.loc['a'].autocorr(lag=1)
```

OR `df.T['a'].autocorr(lag=1)`

In your code it looks like your sending the same row every time.

```
df.loc[0] == df.T[0]  # The first row of the DataFrame
```

You're iterating over the rows of the DataFrame, but not using your iterators

```
autocorr(df.T[0], 1)[0, 1]
```

If you prefer to use your function try changing it to

```
autocorr(row, 1)[0, 1]
```

instead you can use:

```
row.autocorr(lag=t)
```

Since you're iterating over the rows of the DataFrame, the index variable will hold the index of the row from the DF, and the row variable will hold a Series type of the entire row.

Another issue is:

```
df1['outpu1'] = value
```

That way your assigning the value for the whole column.
If the column already exists, you can use loc:

```
df.loc[row_index, col_index] = value
```

If the column doesn't exist you can first calculate the whole column and save it as a Series and than assign to the entire list, or just add it before running your loop

```
df.insert(loc=0, column='output1' value='np.nan')
```

Comment: I tried to use autocorr(row, 1)[0, 1] and row.autocorr(lag=t) in my code, but it still gives me the same value for every row..

Comment: I've edited my answer, forgot to mention that df1['outpu1'] = value will assign the value to the whole column

Comment: I just don't get it. I now tried your adjustment by changing autocorr(row,1)[0,1] AND before I start the line: for index..., I now put: df.insert(loc=0, column='output1' value='np.nan') because it is a new column I want to add. This still gives me the same value.....

Comment: did you also change the line:
df1['outpu1'] =  autocorr(row,1)[0,1]
into
 df1.loc[index, 'outpu1'] = autocorr(row,1)[0,1] ?